# Unable to fetch OneToMany relationship using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to get 5 properties from the Database. I'm able to get all the 4 exception the OneToMany relation.
[image]

**Dua.class**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DUA_DATA_FIL_ID")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<DuaDataFileYearVO> duaDataFileYearList = new ArrayList<DuaDataFileYearVO>();
```

**Hibernate Criteria**

```
    public DuaDataFileShipListObj getDuaInfoForShipping(String duaNumber, DisseminatorListObj disseminatorCodeListObj,
        int index) {

        DuaDataFileShipListObj dataFileShipList = null;
        List<DuaDataFileShipVO> dataFileShipVO = new ArrayList<DuaDataFileShipVO>();
        List<DuaDataFileVO> dataFileVOs = new ArrayList<DuaDataFileVO>();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DuaDataFileVO.class, "dataFile");
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("duaNum", duaNumber))
            // .add(Restrictions.eq("duaDataFileYearList.duaDataFileId", 677L))
                    .add(Restrictions.in("dataDisseminatorCode", disseminatorCodeListObj.getDisseminatorCodes()));

            criteria.createAlias("dataFile.refDataFileExtractingPCTVO", "refDataFileExtractingPCTVO")
                    .createAlias("dataFile.refDataFileVO", "refDataFileVO")
                    .createAlias("dataFile.duaDataFileYearList", "duaDataFileYearList").list();

            criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("duaDataFileId"), "duaDataFileId")
                    .add(Projections.property("dataDisseminatorCode"), "dataDisseminatorCode")
                    .add(Projections.property("refDataFileExtractingPCTVO"), "refDataFileExtractingPCTVO")
                    .add(Projections.property("refDataFileVO"), "refDataFileVO"));
            // criteria.setFirstResult(0);
            criteria.setMaxResults(index);
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DuaDataFileVO.class));


            dataFileVOs = criteria.list();
```

Comment: What property are you trying to get, that isn't being acquired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first glance at your question it looks like you are trying to get property: `duaDataFileYearList` . In your projectionList I don't see this property included, while the other four are.

**Update:** Another way you could accomplish this, is to grab the entire `DuaDataFileVO` object you want, and then get the `DuaDataFileVO.duaDateFileYearList` property from there, instead of trying to get the entity by the properties.

Comment: Added an update in the answer. I'm unsure if you are stuck with wanting to do it this way, it seems overly complicated for something that could be quite simple

Comment: Yeah, thats my last option.